# "ElementNotInteractable element not interactable" - как решить проблему?

Tags: selenium, юнит-тесты, selenium-webdriver, test-automation, testng

Использую Selenium 3.141.59.
Для теста используется сайт генерации mail https://10minutemail.com/

При попытке открыть письмо, отправленное на сгенерированную почту, получаю ошибку ElementNotInteractable element not interactable. Решается Threed.sleep или implicitly wait, но хотелось бы использовать именно explicitly wait.

```
    WebElement mailPage = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
            .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='mail_messages_content']")));
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", mailPage);
    mailPage.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте xpath `//*[@id='mail_messages_content']/div[@class='mail_message'][1]`. Тогда вейтер будет ждать появления хотя бы одного письма. А если придет несколько, возьмет верхнее.

То, что Вы используете сейчас присутствует в DOM и когда ни одного сообщения не пришло, поэтому вейтер заканчивает ожидание, хотя писем еще нет.